# Using spring.net in web api to instantiate controller

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-web-api, spring.net

I want to learn how to make Spring instantiate a Web API controller. I would like to know 2 things:

1. What I should add to my `WebApiConfig` classroom and controllers?
2. How do I declare my controller in the Spring configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

1. You dont need anything in your `WebApiConfig` class and controllers.
2. The same as any object in spring with scope as `singleton=false`.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29957597/1486443).