# How to integrate WebApi 2 with Spring.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, spring.net

Im trying to integrate **WebApi 2** with **Spring.Net** with not success. This is what i have tried:

```
public class MvcApplication : SpringMvcApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

When is creating the `SpringWebApiDependencyResolver` instance, i'm getting this exception:

**Error creating context 'spring.root': Request is not available in this context**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.DependencyResolver = new SpringWebApiDependencyResolver(ContextRegistry.GetContext());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Im using Spring.Net 2.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now is working, the following line was not needed:

```
config.DependencyResolver = new SpringWebApiDependencyResolver(ContextRegistry.GetContext());
```

This is my implementation based on Spring.Net [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/tree/master/examples/Spring/Spring.Mvc5QuickStart/Spring.Mvc5QuickStart):

```
public class MvcApplication : SpringMvcApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // More config...
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        // More config...
    }

    protected override System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver BuildWebApiDependencyResolver()
    {
        var resolver = base.BuildWebApiDependencyResolver();

        var springResolver = resolver as SpringWebApiDependencyResolver;

        if (springResolver != null)
        {
            var resource = new AssemblyResource(
                "assembly://assemblyName/namespace/ChildControllers.xml");
            springResolver.AddChildApplicationContextConfigurationResource(resource);
        }

        return resolver;
    }
}
```

I prefered to keep the common WebApi configuration:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

For registration of controllers in the IoC container is the same as MVC integration:

```
<object type="namespace.PrefixController, assemblyName" singleton="false" >
    <property name="Dependency1" ref="Dependency1" />
</object>
```